# Linux C program: where did this SIGABRT come from?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, glibc, sigabrt

On a Fedora 22 virtual machine, my C program is crashing with SIGABRT.  GDB points at an instruction in the glibc stub for the poll system call.  The disassembly looks like this:

```
 0x7f5359c46662 <poll+34>                mov    %rax,(%rsp)
 0x7f5359c46666 <poll+38>                mov    $0x7,%eax
 0x7f5359c4666b <poll+43>                syscall
>0x7f5359c4666d <poll+45>                mov    (%rsp),%rdi
 0x7f5359c46671 <poll+49>                mov    %rax,%rdx
 0x7f5359c46674 <poll+52>                callq  0x7f5359c5fa30 <__libc_disable_asynccancel>
```

(The stub's source code is in assembly code subject to complex macro processing so it isn't worth quoting here.)

I don't know where the SIGABRT is coming from.

The poll system call manpage doesn't say it can raise a SIGABRT.

There is another thread but it is waiting on a read system call so I don't see how it could send a signal to the crashing thread.

I'm unaware of any agent in the system that might "kill -s SIGABRT" this process.

The code is compiled with -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2, and this could cause SIGABRT but I would expect it to be synchronous so that gdb would point at the code that raised it.

Comment: There is nothing in the kernel that will do this. The signal takes effect upon return from a pending syscall, even if something else caused it. That is, if process A kills process B with SIGABRT, and B is in a syscall, it just "marks" B and B handles it when it can [hence, at return from `poll`]. Put a bkpt on libc's `abort` and `raise` functions to catch internal stuff. Also, bkpt on libc's `kill` with a `cond` of (e.g.) `signo == SIGABRT`. You might also consider using `strace`

Comment: Did the code pass a pointer to valid memory to poll? Did it pass the correct size?

Comment: Craig: It makes sense that the poll might just be the thing that is going on when a SIGABRT is sent to the process.  Now I just have to find out who might be killing it.

Comment: @alk: if it were an invalid poll argument, I would expect EFAULT (or another E* return value).  Or perhaps SIGSEGV.  Not SIGABRT.

Comment: Libraries (including `libc`) might very well call `abort()` when seeing no chance to get out of any nasty calamities. Doing so would result in the process receiving a `SIGABRT`. Did you ran the program using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgind.org)?

Comment: @alk: thanks for the idea.  The problem is intermittent and quite hard to reproduce.  That's why I've still got GDB running on the original core file.  So valgrind isn't what I want to do next.  The tthread itself is at the end of a poll system call (I should check the return value), so I don't see how it could have generated the SIGABRT (I assume that they are synchronous).  The only other thread is in the kernel waiting for a read to complete, so it could not generate a SIGABRT.  So I think that leaves some external agent.  Unless some assumption I'm making is wrong (not unlikely).

Comment: My bet goes on corrupted internals, due to pointers running wild, so I'd still recommend Valgrind. You might like to keep us updated how it turned out. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two potential sources:

- systemd sends SIGABRT when the watchdog timer expires, for instance:
  https://lists.libreswan.org/pipermail/swan-dev/2016-July/001577.html
- the kernel can SIGABRT userland when it has a panic, for instance:
  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/917