# Systemd get reason for watchdog timeout

Tags: linux, systemd

I have to debug an application that always gets killed via **SIGABRT** signal due to some mysterious watchdog timeout in `systemd` after exactly 3 minutes. Is there any logging etc. that helps me find out which of the many systemd parameters triggers the abort?

Comment: Did you stumble upon [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1300212)?

Comment: I don't use Fedora. But is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I would have assumed that this would happen anywhere - it just features in fedora's bugtracker because Red Hat have Poettering working for them ... and no, I don't have a workaround - but there are some great trouble-shooting techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417439/linux-c-program-where-did-this-sigabrt-come-from).

Comment: `coredumpctl list` should list the kept core dumps, and `coredumpctl info 99` for dump 99 might provide some info. If not, use the timestamp to list that part of the journal with `sudo journalctl --since xxx`.

Comment: The answer for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73842628/14393739). There is also a tip to spy the watchdog refresh messages with strace tool.

Answer (score 0):

The application needs to notify watchdog messages to systemd. There are several ways of doing this.
The watchdog internal is set in the systemd service file, and the line looks like

```
WatchdogSec=4s
```

3 minutes seems like a long time, so it looks like the app is not feeding the watchdog.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html for documentation on how to feed the watchdog.