# systemd watchdog for frozen application

Tags: linux, systemd, watchdog

I was checking how the watchdog is implemented in `systemd`. I saw some examples. In these examples I couldn't see that application sends feedback to `systemd`, that it is alive.

How `systemd` will know and restart application if it is frozen? Because in this case, it is not crashed, application is there but frozen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Rob, The watchdog refresh is also a programming subject as systemd offers an API (sd_notify()) for it. So, this question can stay in StackOverflow...

Comment: @RachidK. The question is, "How systemd will know and restart application...?" That is not about programming watchdog.

Comment: @Rob the question title concerns the watchdog management in systemd. And there is an programming part in this subject. The refresh messages are sent thanks to the systemd's API or the raw Linux API on sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the watchdog in a service file consists to set the `WatchdogSec` key with a refresh period. For example, the *udev* service defines a watchdog refresh of 3 minutes:

```c
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/udev.service | grep -Ei "(watchdog|execstart)"
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
WatchdogSec=3min
```

When setting this key, the application is supposed to send at least one watchdog refresh message to `systemd` every 3 minutes. This can be done with `systemd`'s [sd_notify()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd_notify.3.html) API to which is passed the string "WATCHDOG=1".
Hence, `systemd` will kill an application which does not send its refresh message in time. It will eventually restart it depending on the other configuration keys in the service file as described in the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> **WatchdogSec=**
> Configures the watchdog timeout for a service. The watchdog is activated when the start-up is completed. The service must call sd_notify(3) regularly with "WATCHDOG=1" (i.e. the "keep-alive ping"). If the time between two such calls is larger than the configured time, then the service is placed in a failed state and it will be terminated with SIGABRT (or the signal specified by WatchdogSignal=). By setting Restart= to on-failure, on-watchdog, on-abnormal or always, the service will be automatically restarted. The time configured here will be passed to the executed service process in the WATCHDOG_USEC= environment variable. This allows daemons to automatically enable the keep-alive pinging logic if watchdog support is enabled for the service. If this option is used, NotifyAccess= (see below) should be set to open access to the notification socket provided by systemd. If NotifyAccess= is not set, it will be implicitly set to main. Defaults to 0, which disables this feature. The service can check whether the service manager expects watchdog keep-alive notifications. See sd_watchdog_enabled(3) for details. sd_event_set_watchdog(3) may be used to enable automatic watchdog notification support.

**Tip**: The watchdog refresh messages sent to `systemd` can be spied with a tool like `strace`.
`systemd` is normally process#1:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 avril  21 14:54 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
$ pidof init      
1
```

Here is how we can spy the refresh messages sent by *systemd-udevd* process "greping" the `systemd`'s received messages containing the pid of the application process (we use *-tt* option to have the timestamps):

```
$ sudo strace -tt -p1 2>&1 | grep pid=`pidof systemd-udevd`
09:01:17.348636 recvmsg(16, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="WATCHDOG=1", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_control=[{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, cmsg_data={pid=328, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_controllen=32, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_TRUNC|MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 10
09:02:53.345089 recvmsg(16, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="WATCHDOG=1", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_control=[{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, cmsg_data={pid=328, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_controllen=32, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_TRUNC|MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 10
[...]
```

Comment: This is causing me a lot of trouble when debugging the kernel over a serial connection. I think this is what is happening: </br> When remote debug is running, the debugee system is frozen (the whole system is remote gdb takes over). Once I (temporarily) release control, systemd observes that many services have not sent their watchdog refresh messages and kills them. This renders my debugger environment useless. So when I switch to a given thread, the backtrace is gone. This is true for almost all the threads. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score -3):

`systemd` only checks if the PID still exists.
There is to my knowledge no standard way to implement "custom watchdog checks" to verify if a processes is not stuck on a mutex or so.
You can for instance implement your own watchdog as a separate `systemd` unit, that performs a custom check on the supervised process.